# Helper not found

Tags: adminhtml, configuration

I've went through a lot of articles discussing how to solve the error, and yet 3 hours later i cant find the cause of the problem, I'm getting the Helper not found error when navigating to the module admin page at *http://www.appfactory.loc/magento/index.php/admin/push/index/key/17deed03960db48c69ef02d8d3f54768/*:

*Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Appfactory_Push_Helper_Data' not found in C:\Development\stage\grantorino-appfactory-ab\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547*

My configurations are as follows:
**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <AppFactory_Push>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </AppFactory_Push>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <helpers>
      <Push>
        <class>AppFactory_Push_Helper</class>
      </Push>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <Push>
            <class>AppFactory_Push_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Push_resource</resourceModel>
        </Push>
        <Push_resource>
            <class>AppFactory_Push_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <Push>
                    <table>appfactory_push</table>
                </Push>
            </entities>
        </Push_resource>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <Push_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>AppFactory_Push</module>
                <class>AppFactory_Push_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </Push_setup>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <Push>
            <class>AppFactory_Push_Block</class>
        </Push>
    </blocks>

  </global>

  <admin>
      <routers>
          <adminhtml>
              <args>
                  <modules>
                      <AppFactory_Push after="Mage_Adminhtml">AppFactory_Push_Adminhtml</AppFactory_Push>
                  </modules>
              </args>
          </adminhtml>
      </routers>
  </admin>

  <adminhtml>
      <layout>
          <updates>
              <appfactory_push>
                  <file>appfactory_push.xml</file>
              </appfactory_push>
          </updates>
      </layout>
  </adminhtml>

  <default>
      <Push>
        <view>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <amazon_access_key_id></amazon_access_key_id>
            <amazon_secret_access_key></amazon_secret_access_key>
            <amazon_region>us-west-2</amazon_region>
            <amazon_arn></amazon_arn>
            <amazon_topic>3</amazon_topic>
        </view>
    </Push>
  </default>

</config>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <menu>
         <basic>
            <children>
                <manage>
                    <title>Push Notifications</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/push</action>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                </manage>
            </children>
         </basic>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <Push>
                                        <title>App Factory Push Notifications</title>
                                    </Push>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>      
</config>
```

**Helper File**
*C:\Development\stage\grantorino-appfactory-ab\magento\app\code\local\AppFactory\Push\Helper\Data.php*

```
<?php
class AppFactory_Push_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Comment: Are Compilation and cache disabled?  No apc / varnish?  Are files readable?  Pls also post your helper path and the file contents.

Comment: @Amasty just added the file to the question, nop all cache disabled, files very readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named Data.php in app/code/local/AppFactory/Push/Helper with the following content:

```
<?php
class Appfactory_Push_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

and the error should be gone.
If not, change the translator module to something like 'core' instead of 'yourmodule'.

The error is normally because you are trying to translate a string without the proper module and it gives a blank page.

It might be anywhere in the .php files, call normally is Mage::helper('somemodule')->__('string') or inside the .xml files is something like translate="" module=""

Comment: i already have it :(, i added the file to the question

Comment: Change the translator module to something like 'core' instead of 'yourmodule'. The error is normally because you are trying to translate a string without the proper module and it gives a blank page.

Comment: where? im not adding any translate attributes in the xml

Comment: It might be anywhere in the .php files, call normally is Mage::helper('somemodule')->__('string') or inside the .xml files is something like translate="" module=""

Comment: but if its not in the xml or php files it wont be called, right?

Comment: Im 90% sure this is your problem. Keep looking, normally this happens in a grid or a form.

Comment: thanks man u rock, can you create a separate answer to mark it as the answer

Comment: Done, just edited the original answer.

Comment: so what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in acl. Try below code

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <Push translate="title" module="AppFactory_Push">
                                        <title>App Factory Push Notifications</title>
                                    </Push>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

It will most probably work.